# Краш в gcc при создании статического глобального объекта

Tags: c++, gcc, static, clang

Почему `clang` исполняет верно, а `gcc` крашит эту программу? [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:9,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:9,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:9,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:9),source:%27struct+A+%7B%0A++++A()%3B%0A++++%7EA()%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astatic+A+a%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A%0A%7D%0A%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0AA::A()+%7B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22A::A()%5Cn%22%3B%0A%7D%0A%0AA::%7EA()+%7B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22A::%7EA()%5Cn%22%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:g122,compilerName:%27%27,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27%27,source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:clang_trunk,compilerName:%27%27,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27%27,source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
struct A {
    A();
    ~A();
};

static A a;

int main() {

}

#include <iostream>

A::A() {
    std::cout << "A::A()\n";
}

A::~A() {
    std::cout << "A::~A()\n";
}
```

Comment: Static Initialization Order Fiasco

Comment: неправильный порядок инициализации переменной `std :: cout` и `a`

Comment: @user7860670 здесь же один файл

Comment: @AlexGlebe а почему в `clang` работает?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::cout` требует инициализации перед использованием.

Обычно эта инициализация происходит автоматически, за счет того, что `#include <iostream>` содержит в том числе `static` переменную, которая в своем конструкторе делает эту инициализацию. (Хотя в libstdc++-13 вроде придумали [способ поумнее](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2023/04/03/leaner-libstdc-gcc-13).)

Но чтобы это нормально работало, `#include <iostream>` должен находиться над глобальными переменными, которые используют `std::cout`. (И то для шаблонных переменных это не спасает.)

Решение - либо инклудить `<iostream>` повыше, либо инициализировать руками, вот так:

```
std::ios_base::Init init;
std::cout << "A::A()\n";
```

Comment: 1) Почему в `clang` работает? 2) "И то для шаблонных переменных это не спасает" - можно пример, что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: @Hjo (1) Та версия кланга, которую вы выбрали, на этом сайте использует вообще libstdc++-14 (можно проверить напечатав `_GLIBCXX_RELEASE`), который уже не использует трюк со статической переменной (читайте ссылку в ответе). Если переключиться на Clang 16, то словите краш, потому что на этом сайте он, судя по значению макроса, использует libstdc++-12.

Comment: @Hjo (2) Вот, смотрите: https://godbolt.org/z/76d6zv6EW Как видите, для шаблонных переменных порядок инициализации зависит от компилятора. Про это можно почитать [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Dynamic_initialization) (пункт 1).